# GUI testing tool for Java based application

Tags: java, swing, testing, user-interface, awt

Requirements:

1. Maximum coverage
2. free license would be a big advantage
3. compatibility with different frameworks
4. it should work on old JVM (starting from Java 3).

What could you recommend me please?

Comment: Another alternative is http://retest.org

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [SwingExplorer](http://www.swingexplorer.com/):

> Swing Explorer is an Open-Source tool for Swing application developers
>   which is intended for visual exploring of a Swing-based application
>   internals.
>
> - Find all top-level components (Windows, Frames, Dialogs)
> - Browse through component hierarchy
> - Monitor AWT/Swing events
> - Debug 2D graphics
> - Dig into source code
> - Monitor threading rule violations

Answer (score 0):

For GUI testing would prefer Jmeter as its free ware and much easy to test application and also having functionality for Load and Performance testing.

```
http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi
```

Answer (score 0):

For swing I've used http://www.qfs.de/en/qftest/ which is commercial .

I've heard about http://code.google.com/p/fest/.

Answer (score -1):

Use selenium IDE ,
use can perform automation testing ,it even generates JUnit test cases.
check a tutorial  for more info
http://www.jroller.com/selenium/

Comment: As I understand selenium is for browser testing only? I need to test desktop application.

Comment: yeah its for browser testing